# How to turn off screen of android with terminal emulator?

Tags: screen, terminal

How to turn off screen of android with terminal emulator?  I am using Android 5.0.

Comment: In ADB, try 'adb shell input keyevent 26' (no ' marks)

Comment: @DanB From an in-Android Terminal emulator, it's just `input keyevent 26`. It's worth noting that the phone didn't accept this event, unless sent as root.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Ah OK. I was not sure at what point to shorten it to.

Comment: @DanB Your version is perfect for use from **adb**, and it may also avoid the user to be root.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Yes, which is why I suggested it in the first place. I left it as a comment because its too blunt/short for an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this, depending on if you have root or not on your device.

**If you use root**

If you have rooted, run:

```
su
input keyevent 26
```

In any good terminal emulator.

**If you have not rooted**

If you haven't rooted, either root, or:

1. Install ADB (Instructions vary between windows, Mac and Linux)
2. Enable "USB Debugging in settings > developer options (if you cannot find developer options, tap the build number in 'about phone' seven times.)
3. Connect your device to the PC, and connect via ADB
4. Run: `adb shell input keyevent 26`

Comment: Thaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaank's its work 5/5 :)

Comment: @MBZXI If it works, please mark it as an answer (that tick under the downvote button)